# runtime error sigsegv

Tags: c

i am getting runtime error sigsegv, i don't understand the problem with this code.
this is a program to match initial substring with with array of string having maximum priority.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
int main() {
    int T,i,N;
    char si[T][1000];
   long vi[T];
scanf("%d",&T);
for(i=0;i<T;++i)
            scanf("%s%ld",&si[i],&vi[i]);

scanf("%d",&N);
while(N--) {
           char str[1000];
           scanf("%s",str);
             int j,maxPindex=-1;
             long maxPriority=LONG_MIN;
             int l=strlen(str);
             for(j=0;j<T;++j) {
                     if(strlen(si[j])>=l && strncmp(str,si[j],l)==0 &&  vi[j]>maxPriority) {
                                               maxPriority=vi[j];
                                               maxPindex=j;
                     }                                                
             }
             //free(str);
             if(maxPindex==-1) printf("NO\n");
             else printf("%s\n",si[maxPindex]);
 }
return (0);

}
```

Comment: "please post answer as soon as possible": OK.

Comment: Please fix your spacebar and turn on your compiler warnings as soon as possible. Then ask yourself how big you expect `si` to be.

Answer (score 1):

It crashes already when it tries to create the variable "si". A C variable inside a function, such as the variable "T", starts with random garbage as its value. For example, it could contain 918128238. Then, when trying to create "si", this would be a very large array, and it doesn't fit.

You need to read a value for "T" before "si" and "vi" are created. That is, move your scanf before the declarions of "si" and "vi".